# How to run my program at startup like CHKDSK

Tags: windows, windows-xp, exe, startup, winlogon

I noticed that if I ran `CHKDSK /F c:` and told it to run next time i boot, it runs before winlogon starts... [image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS2E-nqtmEekFO_Ca2eBdma4LfKs_83nN3u_aO2aVR0vQf9Zeu0bWKFgx2-) (Windows XP)
How do I run my exe like this? Thanks!

Comment: Add it to the [BootExecute key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963230.aspx).  However, it has to be a native program, i.e., using the kernel API rather than Win32.

Comment: so, can i run a Batch-file with this?

Comment: No.  The batch interpreter is a Win32 program, not a native program.

Comment: Well, what programs could I run? I need to rename some protected files before Windows starts, and copy some files too... @HarryJohnston

Comment: You would have to write your own program.  Or do it a completely different way, like booting to Windows PE.

Comment: @HarryJohnston if I am booting to Windows PE, how do I tell automatically where the primary windows installation is?

Comment: I generally only deal with machines that are configured in a uniform way, so I know it's on partition 2 or whatever.  But I guess you could look up the volume GUID, or the partition number, or whatever, while building your PE instance and save it to a file.  It isn't trivial, but it's doable.  (If you're using batch, I found that one useful trick was to save information of that sort to a .cmd file in the format `SET foo=whatever` and then I could `call` the file to set the environment variable.)

Comment: (If I remember rightly, if Windows PE is booted off a hard disk, the C drive is whichever partition Windows PE booted from.  That gives you a useful starting point.)

Comment: @harryjohnston I've only ever booted PE of a disc... How do I go about the MBR stuff if i set up a temporary PE installation?

Comment: Everything you need is in the deployment kit documentation.  Personally, I usually install PE on the main Windows partition (rather than the active partition) because that way you can switch back and forth just by changing which partition is active.  (Which you can do with `diskpart`.)